# how to add new font awesome icon to my odoo module?

Tags: javascript, python, css, odoo, font-awesome

I'm working on customizing web_notify oca module which sends a pop-up notification to screen, it contains some varients of notification each one has a font awesome icons that appear on the notification it defines the icons in this js file

```
odoo.define('web_notify.Notification', function (require) {
"use strict";

var Notification = require('web.Notification');

Notification.include({
    icon_mapping: {
        'success': 'fa-thumbs-up',
        'danger': 'fa-exclamation-triangle',
        'warning': 'fa-exclamation',
        'info': 'fa-info',
        'default': 'fa-lightbulb-o',
    },
    init: function () {
        this._super.apply(this, arguments);
        // Delete default classes
        this.className = this.className.replace(' o_error', '');
        // Add custom icon and custom class
        this.icon = (this.type in this.icon_mapping) ?
            this.icon_mapping[this.type] :
            this.icon_mapping['default'];
        this.className += ' o_' + this.type;
    },
});

});
```

I'm searching on awesome website and I need to to add an icon that I found it declaration

```
  <i class="fas fa-mosque">
  </i>
```

say if I need to replace fa-thumbs-up with the new one how can I do that

Answer (score 0):

Did you include the latest stylesheet link for font awesome?It seems to work fine here.

```html
  <html>
  <head>  
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.13.0/css/all.min.css">
  </head>
  <body>
  <i class="fas fa-mosque">
  </i>
  <body>
  </html>
```

Comment: how can i add this to odoo file

Comment: I misunderstood at the first place.Try replacing 'fa-thumbs-up' with 'fas fa-mosque' or 'f678' in 'success': 'fa-thumbs-up'.

Comment: if I replace it, it doesn't display any icon

Comment: https://www.odoo.com/nl_NL/forum/help-1/question/add-font-awesome-icon-in-odoo-menu-81400   Does it help?

Comment: how odoo will recognize fas fa-mosque , it's not declared in any files before

Comment: So, where does the fa-thumbs-up declared?It must be declared somewhere in your project files. Maybe a local src is given or link to the font awesome is used.

Comment: so if i found the file bath that contains the awesome fonts , how can I add a new one there

Comment: Are u using a plugin for that or an external file named "fontawesome.css"?

Comment: external file on the base module

Comment: You have to replace that file. Download from here: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Nezfgypue_plOmMlx0lKcXlC93fzi8xN/view